# Integrate Stripe to HTML pricing table

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe.js

I'm trying to integrate Stripe to an HTML pricing table like this one: 
[image]
These are recurring subscription plans.

Is this possible with Stripe for a non-PHP programmer? I was building the site in HTML.

Comment: No matter what at some point there is server side code to be written (in whatever language)

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it with PHP